# PHP Mod_Rewrite & Query String

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this code to remove .php from my other urls.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

And using this .htaccess rewrite rule to make my URLs pretty.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?item/(.*?)/?$ /item.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /item\.php\?name=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?item\.php$ /item/%1? [L,R=301]
```

So now

```
site.com/item.php?name=roses
```

Becomes

```
site.com/item/roses
```

But when I use `$_GET["name"]` in my item.php script I'm getting this as a result:

```
roses.php/roses
```

Any ideas what I need to change or do to get just my query string? roses.

Thank you